# What's happening with my alternator?

Tags: honda, alternator, wiring

So, my car has blown up to 6 alternators thus far. Luckily I had a life time warranty replacement on it and did not have to pay for it. Autozone is definitely going to void that warranty on my next replacement for sure but I am confused as hell as to why it keeps going bad.

The issue starts with the battery light at first taking an extra second or two to illuminate on the dashboard and then it does not illuminate at all. When I put jumper cables on the positive side of the battery and connect it to the alternator positive output the light comes on and the alternator is actually charging. So my guess was the cable connected to the alternator was bad. And while it was corroded after re-doing a huge part of it and using battery terminal wires to hook it back up it seemed fine for a while lasting the longest of the 6 but then again it did the same thing. I thought my wiring was bad but everything seemed fine and unchanged. I also get my alternator tested every single time I get it replaced and it tests bad every single time which is adding to my confusion.

I also grabbed a whole new wiring harness with every plug from a junkyard but unfortunately after hours of work I grabbed it from an engine without EGR valve so had to swap back.

So my questions are:

1- Why would the battery light not illuminate when the auxiliary power is on

2- Why would it illuminate back on when I connect the battery terminal plus side to the alternator output

3- If the above suggests a wiring issue why would a new alternator fix it

4- If it is a wiring issue despite doing my best attempt and re-doing the wiring twice am I going to have to get a new harness?

5- What are some ways to do testing on the wires? What voltage read out should be between the positive side and alternator side?

6- What are the conditions for the battery light to illuminate on auxiliary power in the dashboard?

The vehicle in question is an 2005 Honda Civic HX edition.

Comment: It's really hard to say but generally there are only 3 things needed to check here.  First the alternator itself, which you have replace more than once.  The battery, which you should have checked.  And finally the wiring which you should investigate.  The only thing that I can imagine is a short-circuit of some sort which is overloading the output of the alternator and causing it to fail.  I'm not familiar with the 05 Civic but I assume it's like most recent cars with the voltage regulator built into the alternator.

Comment: Maybe AZ sells crappy alternators.

Comment: @jwh20 many cars now have alternators with regulation control from the ecu to comtrol output relative to engime load such as under acceleration etc.